# Scipy Weibull CDF calculation

Tags: python, scipy, cdf, weibull

I'm doing survival calculations in Scipy and can't get the correct values.

My code:

```
x, a, c = 1000, 1.5, 5000

vals = exponweib.cdf(x,a,c,loc=0,scale=1)
```

`vals` should equal 0.085559356392783004, but I'm getting 0 instead.

If I define my own function I get the right answer:

```
def weibCumDist(x,a,c):
    return 1-np.exp(-(x/c)**a)
```

I could just use my own function, but I'm curious as to what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: A value of `c` equaling 5000 is enormous, are you sure that's correct? I receive a runtime error because the power exponent is so huge.

Answer (score 4):

You haven't correctly mapped your parameters to those of scipy.  To implement the equivalent of your `weibCumDist`:

```
In [22]: x = 1000

In [23]: a = 1.5

In [24]: c = 5000

In [25]: exponweib.cdf(x, 1, a, loc=0, scale=c)
Out[25]: 0.08555935639278299
```

Note that [`exponweib`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.exponweib.html) is the [*exponentiated* Weibull distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiated_Weibull_distribution).

You probably want to use `scipy.stats.weibull_min`.  This is the implementation of the distribution that is often referred to as "the" Weibull distribution:

```
In [49]: from scipy.stats import weibull_min

In [50]: weibull_min.cdf(x, a, loc=0, scale=c)
Out[50]: 0.08555935639278299
```