# Weibull Distribution Scipy

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy, weibull

Following is the code I wrote for Weibull Distribution which generates data which will fit a Weibull distribution and try to plot the same

```
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = stats.exponweib.rvs(a=1, c=2.09, scale=10.895, loc=0, size=2500)

plt.plot(data, stats.exponweib.pdf(data, *stats.exponweib.fit(data, 1, 1, scale=02, loc=0))

_ = plt.hist(data, bins = np.linspace(0, 16, 33), normed=True, alpha=0.5)

plt.show()
```

My Question :-

I want a single line interpolation over the bins, why I am getting messed up plot ?

Comment: Bytheway, "`scipy.stats.weibull_min` is the distribution often referred to as "the" Weibull distribution" -- [scipy-weibull-cdf-calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27432222/scipy-weibull-cdf-calculation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matplotlib `plot` function plots the curve connecting the points in the order in which the points are given.  To get the curve that you expect, sort `data` before plotting it.  E.g.:

```
data = stats.exponweib.rvs(a=1, c=2.09, scale=10.895, loc=0, size=2500)
data.sort()
plt.plot(data, stats.exponweib.pdf(data, *stats.exponweib.fit(data, 1, 1, scale=2, loc=0)))
```

Comment: Thanks dude .. :)